# Ubuntu is stuck when starting up due to the nouveau

Tags: 20.04, graphics, nouveau

My laptop which is running Ubuntu 20.04 is stuck when starting up, and it shows the following content on the screen.

[image]

I can forcibly shut down and then restart it successfully. It seems this is a problem or error with the nouveau driver. The graphics card is Mesa Intel UHD graphics.

[image]

Comment: Intel built-in graphics do not need the Noveau driver, which is only for Nvidia cards. Why do you have Noveau installed? did you install it, or did you have an Nvidia card before?